# Posiciones en barra NAV de líneas y título de web, con tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind

Buen día a todos.
Estoy iniciando mi experiencia con tailwind y pude crear un NAV bar en la web.
Estoy utilizando laravel 8 y php 7.4.
Al querer colocar un botón hamburguesa o las 3 barritas para mostrar o esconder una barra laterial junto con el título de la web, estos quedan uno sobre otro, en vez de quedar al lado.

Algo así:

=  Portal web

Código:

```
<body class="bg-gray-100 text-gray-800">
    <nav class="flex py-5 bg-blue-900 text-white" >
        <div class="w-1/2 px-2 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 mx-auto" >
            <button id="sidebarBtn" class="px-4 py-2 text-white-700 text-2xl rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-black-700">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button> 
            <p class="text-2xl font-bold"><a href="#">Portal Web</a></p>
        </div>
    </nav>

</body>
```

Algo me falta, o algo me sobra. No he podido ordenar bien el código.-

Agradecido, quedo atento.